# Which response returns twitter on verify credentials API request?

Tags: ruby, api, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am working with twitter API and have a question about `GET account/verify_credentials` API.

[Here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials) is described only one type of request with one type of response and without additional options:

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json
```

**Question**:
What if I add `include_email=true` parameter to request? Where `email` key and value will be located in json response?

```
GET https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true
```

Why I am asking - Currently I made a request to twitter support about accessing user's email (include_email option) and waiting for an access. But it will be good if I made a mocks for these response and complete tests now.

Comment: Hey I am also doing same thing but in android. i want to ask you that are you passing consumer key and secret key and all that parameter to this request?

Comment: @AiyazParmar Hi, no. consumer key and secret keys needs only to initialize twitter client. Please see the list of request parameters here - https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/account/verify_credentials